# Mysql if Null or Empty String then Show N/A

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I'm new to mysqsl and I'm trying to display N/A if the return data is empty or NULL but my query is unrecognized statement type. What do you think is wrong with my query? wrong placement of code?

```
CASE when 'Earliest Time Opened' = '' or 'Earliest Time Opened' is 'Null'
 then 'N/A'
 ELSE
        SELECT (date_format(d.date_opened, '%r') as 'Earliest Time Opened'
        FROM  daily_report  d  JOIN userinfo ui
        ON d.userid= ui.id
        WHERE d.date_opened >= date_sub(curdate(), interval 0 day)
        AND d.survey_at_what_blh = 'Bagong Silang' AND ui.status='Employee'
        ORDER BY d.date_opened DESC
        limit 1
```

END

Comment:  Please, easy on the ALL CAPS. It's considered YELLING.

Comment: Oh sorry about that let me change the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `IF` with `ISNULL` here:

```sql
SELECT IF(ISNULL(d.date_opened), 'N/A', DATE_FORMAT(d.date_opened, '%r')) AS `Earliest Time Opened`
FROM daily_report d
INNER JOIN userinfo ui ON d.userid = ui.id
WHERE
    d.date_opened >= CURDATE() AND
    d.survey_at_what_blh = 'Bagong Silang' AND
    ui.status = 'Employee'
ORDER BY
    d.date_opened DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

If you really wanted to use a `CASE` expression, then it would need to appear *inside* the select clause, something like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(d.date_opened, '%r') IS NOT NULL
            THEN DATE_FORMAT(d.date_opened, '%r')
            ELSE 'N/A' END AS `Earliest Time Opened`
```

But `COALESCE` is much more terse and appropriate here.

Comment: its working but its returning empty string should I used or? sorry I'm newbie in mysql